# Can you implement IDisposable on a dynamically created form

Tags: vb.net, module, idisposable

I am experimenting with a messagebox that when displayed does so with the visual style being used by the main application (but for that I wouldn't waste my time re-inventing the wheel).  As it transpires this has turned into quite an interesting little exercise and in the process I have learnt a great deal along the way.

First and foremost I'm doing this in VB so I have placed all of my code in it's own dll, and in turn in  a Module so that in the final projects that reference this dll the end user (me in this case ) can just call MyDll.MessageBox.show().

First time that I call this everything works exactly as expected, second time around however odd things started to happen.  After much experimentation I can only conclude that after my message box is closed first time around it just isn't being disposed of properly.

Now I can't implement IDisposable on the module that contains the code to create the message box because VB doesn't allow it.  I have tried to explicitly dispose of the object as it closed but clearly that isn't working.  I'm missing something but to be perfectly honest I'm a little out of my depth on this one.

I have read through various posts here (although almost all relate to c# which and to areas where you can actively implement IDisposable), so I'm still none the wiser.

Am I starting to look at the right area (IDisposable) in which case how ought I to proceed given that this is emanating from a module, or am I looking in entirely the wrong area?

Thanks

Code:

This is show method:

```
Public Function Show(ByVal text As String) As DialogResult
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("text", "You need to supply text for the message itself.")
    Else
        MessageText = text
    End If

    MessageCaption = String.Empty
    SetMessageButtons(VtlMessageBoxButtons.OK)
    IconSelected = False

    Return CreateVtlMessageBox()
End Function
```

Which leads to the CreateVtlMessageBox

```
Private Function CreateVtlMessageBox() As DialogResult
    'check to see that we have a theme to use
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentC1ThemeInUse) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("No theme has been set for the message box to use.  Please ensure that you have set a value for the property 'CurrentC1ThemeInUse'.")
        Exit Function
    End If

    'we have a theme so we'll continue
    _maximumWidth = CType((SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width * 0.6), Integer)
    _maximumHeight = CType((SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height * 0.9), Integer)
    frm = New Form With {.Text = MessageCaption,
                               .MaximizeBox = False,
                               .MinimizeBox = False,
                               .ShowIcon = False,
                               .ShowInTaskbar = False,
                               .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
                               .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent}

    AddHandler frm.Load, AddressOf FormLoad
    AddHandler frm.FormClosing, AddressOf FormClosing
    AddHandler frm.FormClosed, AddressOf FormClosed

    Dim result As DialogResult
    Using frm
        result = frm.ShowDialog
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

I added formClosing and Closed methods by way of an experiment, I think in truth that they are redundant and I will remove them.

```
Private Sub FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    If sl isNot nothing Then
        sl.Dispose
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub FormClosed(sender As Object,e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    frm.Dispose
End Sub
```

For clarification sl is a label control which I had originally thought to be the issue.
FormLoad on the other hand does the donkey work and I think the root of the problem may well be there and the methods it in turn calls.

```
Private Sub FormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    frm.Size = New Size(_maximumWidth, _maximumHeight)
    _maximumLayoutWidth = frm.ClientSize.Width - LeftPadding - RightPadding
    _maximumLayoutHeight = frm.ClientSize.Height - TopPadding - BottomPadding

    If IconSelected Then
        CreateAndPositionIconOnForm()
    End If
    SetTheText()
    PositionAndSizeTheSuperLabel()
    SetTheOptimumSizeForTheForm()
    LayoutTheForm()
    If frm Is Nothing Then
        Return
    Else
        If IconSelected Then
            frm.Controls.Add(IconPanel)
        End If
        frm.Controls.Add(sl)
    End If




    Dim lThemeName As String = CurrentC1ThemeInUse
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lThemeName) Then
        Dim lThemeLocator As New C1ThemeLocator(locationType:=C1ThemeLocator.LocationType.ThemesFolder, themeName:=lThemeName)
        Dim lTheme As C1Theme = New C1ThemeLocator(lThemeLocator).GetTheme()

        C1ThemeController.ApplyThemeToControlTree(frm, lTheme)
    End If

    If NoCancelButton Then
        'disable the close Button
        Disable(frm)
    End If


End Sub
```

Adding  the SetTheTex method below solved the problem with sl by explicitly disposing of it when I call the message box second time around.

```
Private Sub SetTheText
     If sl Is Nothing Then
        sl = New C1SuperLabel With {.Text = MessageText}
    Else
        sl.Dispose
         sl = New C1SuperLabel With {.Text = MessageText}
    End If
End Sub
```

Now the second time you call the message box it doesn't throw an unhandled exception as it did before I disposed of sl but it does duplicate all of the buutons, and will continue to add to them each time that it is called again.

The two bits of code that pertain to that are shown below.

```
Private Sub SetTheOptimumSizeForTheForm()
    Dim ncWidth As Integer = frm.Width - frm.ClientSize.Width
    Dim ncHeight As Integer = frm.Height - frm.ClientSize.Height

    Dim messageRowWidth As Integer
    If IconSelected Then
        messageRowWidth = sl.Width + IconToMessagePadding + IconPanel.Width
    Else
        messageRowWidth = sl.Width + RightPadding
    End If




    _buttonsRowWidth = GetWidthOfAllAvailableButtons()
    Dim captionWidth As Integer = GetCaptionSize().Width + CloseButtonWidth



    Dim maxItemWidth As Integer = Math.Max(messageRowWidth, _buttonsRowWidth)
    Dim requiredWidth As Integer = LeftPadding + maxItemWidth + RightPadding + ncWidth
    'Since Caption width is not client width, we do the check here
    If requiredWidth < captionWidth Then
        requiredWidth = captionWidth

    End If

    Dim requiredHeight As Integer
    If IconSelected Then
        requiredHeight = TopPadding + Math.Max(sl.Height, IconPanel.Height) + ItemPadding + ItemPadding + GetButtonSize().Height + BottomPadding + ncHeight
    Else
        requiredHeight = TopPadding + sl.Height + ItemPadding + ItemPadding + GetButtonSize().Height + BottomPadding + ncHeight
    End If


    If requiredHeight > _maximumHeight Then
        sl.Height -= requiredHeight - _maximumHeight
    End If
    Dim height As Integer = Math.Min(requiredHeight, _maximumHeight)
    Dim width As Integer = Math.Min(requiredWidth, _maximumWidth)

    frm.Size = New Size(width, height)


End Sub






Private Sub LayoutTheForm()

    If IconSelected Then
        IconPanel.Location = New Point(LeftPadding, TopPadding)
        sl.Location = New Point(LeftPadding + IconPanel.Width + IconToMessagePadding * (If(IconPanel.Width = 0, 0, 1)), TopPadding)
    Else
        sl.Location = New Point(LeftPadding + IconToMessagePadding, TopPadding)
    End If



    Dim buttonSize As Size = GetButtonSize()

    'buttons need to be positioned from the right of the message box
    Dim allButtonsWidth As Integer = _buttonsRowWidth + ButtonPadding
    Dim firstButtonX As Integer = CType(frm.ClientSize.Width - allButtonsWidth, Integer)
    Dim firstButtonY As Integer = frm.ClientSize.Height - BottomPadding - buttonSize.Height


    Dim nextButtonLocation As Point = New Point(firstButtonX, firstButtonY)
    Dim foundDefaultButton As Boolean = False
    Dim i As Integer


    For Each button As String In MessageButtons
        Dim buttonCtrl As C1Button = AddMessageBoxButton(button, buttonSize, nextButtonLocation)
        nextButtonLocation.X += buttonSize.Width + ButtonPadding
        i = buttonCtrl.Location.Y
        buttonCtrl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom And AnchorStyles.Right
        frm.Controls.Add(buttonCtrl)
    Next

End Sub
```

I hope this helps to follow my logic, or lack thereof!

Comment: it sounds like it is actually a Dialog used in MessageBox fashion.  What it is and how it is used (Your Code) and what "odd things" means  would help to know what the problem(s) are.  IDisposable does not sound like it applies.

Comment: qYou're absolutely correct that it is a dialog.  II did't originally add code as there is a fair bit of it, but I'll add as much as I think will give you the gist of what is happening.

Comment: it is probably an issue of how it is called/used.  start with how it is invoked

Comment: Finally I found the issue I believe.  The superLabel (sl) clearly was being disposed but by explicitly doing so second time around that worked.  I should also have disposed of the array used to store the message box buttons as well though and that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest that you remove all of this code from the module. This isn't really the use of a module. Instead, create a subclass of form.

```
Class MyMessageBox
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New(ByVal messageCaption As String)

        'we have a theme so we'll continue
        _maximumWidth = CType((SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width * 0.6), Integer)
        _maximumHeight = CType((SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height * 0.9), Integer)

        Text = messageCaption,
        MaximizeBox = False,
        MinimizeBox = False,
        ShowIcon = False,
        ShowInTaskbar = False,
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent}

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Show(ByVal text As String) As DialogResult
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("text", "You need to supply text for the message itself.")
        Else
            MessageText = text
        End If

        MessageCaption = String.Empty
        SetMessageButtons(VtlMessageBoxButtons.OK)
        IconSelected = False

        'check to see that we have a theme to use
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentC1ThemeInUse) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("No theme has been set for the message box to use.  Please ensure that you have set a value for the property 'CurrentC1ThemeInUse'.")
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim frm = New MyMessageBox(MessageCaption)

        Dim result As DialogResult
        Using frm
            result = frm.ShowDialog
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub FormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub

End Class
```

The idea is that the shared function creates an instance of a inherited form with all the special feature you want to add to it. That way, that form can handle the IDispose. All of your events will also be part of that form instead of being in a module. Each form will also have their own instance of their variable which will reduce conflict.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and the code to illustrate.  If nothing else it has finally caused the penny to drop as to how one should go about sub classing for which it's a definite plus one.